# Typedef requirement in Objective-C vs C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

From my reading, I am gathering that you don't need typedef in C++ in the same way you do in Objective-C. For example, in C++ you can do this:

```
enum Order {first,second,third};
Order myOrder;
myOrder=first;
```

But in Objective-C, the line `Order myOrder;` would first require a `typedef`:

```
typedef enum {first,second,third} Order; //noting also the placement of Order at the end
Order myOrder;
myOrder=first;
```

Correct? Without the `typedef` in Objective-C you'd have to define `myOrder` by repeating the `enum`:

```
enum Order {first,second,third};
enum Order myOrder;
myOrder=first;
```

If in fact this is all correct, I find it a bit odd that there is this type of syntactic differences in the languages, since both are based on C and none of this is unique to the object-oriented natures of the languages, thus should be just straight C I would think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually that's not strange at all, Objective-C is a superset of C and in C you must use the keyword `enum` again (as for the keyword `struct`) so that's coherent.

If you want the agile version switch to Objective-C++ which, being a superset of C++ allows the less verbose version without the requirement of a `typedef`.

Actually Objective-C is not *based on* C, it is C + Obective-C so it's a real extension to it.

Comment: Interesting, so c++ is not really the standard C syntax with added features much like Objective-C is standard C syntax with added features?

Comment: C++ is a language on its own which has many features in common to C. Objective-C is really C + something added. A valid C program always compiles with an Objective-C compiler, this is not true with a C++ compiler. Just forget particular idioms for which my assertion could not be true, take it in general.

Comment: I assume that strict C code may not compile in Objective-C++?

Comment: it may or may not compile, it depends what specific features are you using. Mostly yes but certain things won't.